# Window Insets gets ignored when animating TopAppBar

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I created a test code to reproduce the problem mentioned in the title of this question. I believe this to be a glitch in the framework at the moment and am here just to get a second opinion on the matter.

What I wanted to achieve here is simple , to animate a TopAppBar out of the screen on the click on button. Keep in mind I am using material3

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TestScaffoldInsets() {
  val showTopAppBar = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
  Scaffold(topBar = {
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = showTopAppBar.value) {
      CenterAlignedTopAppBar(title = {
        Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
          MediumHeading(text = "I am a topappbar")
          
        }
      })
    }
  }) { padding ->
    Text(text = "Click Me", modifier = Modifier
      .padding(padding)
      .clickable {
        showTopAppBar.value = !showTopAppBar.value
      })
  }
}
```

If you run this code , you would see that the animation doesn't work as expected. The body of the Scaffold momentarily goes underneath the status bar there by ignoring the window inset.

Please see the video of this here (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fhoyhPaA64N2Z4KyaqOlTvWkRmbE_mbH/view?usp=share_link)

Anyone came across this before?

Comment: In my opinion, this is not a "glitch in the framework", since Scaffold is not a part of the framework. Scaffold is a component from material design and it supports certain behaviors described in the material design specs. If you need something custom like here, you may try to bend it, but if it's not possible, you will probably have to create your own component.